# print carriage return in OSX bash

Tags: macos, bash

Why does `echo`-ing a carriage return from OSX Terminal behave differently than from a `bash` script?

From Terminal in OSX 10.7.3:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ echo -ne "hello\rbye"
byelo
```

But I see a different result from `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -ne "hello\rbye"
```

...running `test.sh` gives me:

```
$ ./test.sh
byehello
```

I was expecting `byelo`. Why is it different? and how do I correct this?

Comment: If the script contains just `echo -e "hello"` is the word `hello` printed in the 1st or 4th column?

Comment: Hmm... two ideas would be to refer to echo by its actual path, and for debugging to do an echo $BASH_VERSION and see if it's the same.  You could even try to check on the resulting processes (you do have some sort of 'ps' command right?), possibly by putting it in a while loop so you get a chance to see one of them.  Oh, and probably unecessary, but can you hexdump the script file and make sure it's what it's intended to be, and hasn't been stored oddly by some editor?

Comment: Something to do with your prompt? (echo $PS1)

Comment: This might be interesting: compare 'echo --verson' vs '/bin/echo --version' (or whatever it is, you can which it in backticks which I can't post in a comment) vs the former placed in the script.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, They all print the same version: `3.2.48(1)-release`. ("They" = {`echo $BASH_VERSION`, `/bin/echo $BASH_VERSION`, `bash -c 'echo $BASH_VERSION`}). And I assume you meant `$BASH_VERSION` in your latest comment (because `echo` doesn't have a `--version` parameter).

Comment: @JohnMee, not sure how my prompt would screw up the output of my script, but here it is: `\n\[\033[1;32m\]\u\[\033[1;30m\]@\[\033[34m\]\h \[\033[1;30m\]: \[\033[1;33m\]\w\n\[\033[1;30m\]$\[\033[m\]`

Comment: @user46874 actually, echo as a program ('which echo') probably does have a --version, but echo as a shell built-in likely does not.  That's the distinction I'm getting at.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Hmm, ok. I just tried `which echo --version` and got `--version`. (I do have backticks around `which echo`...I just don't know how to show them inside a codeblock)

Comment: Does which echo give you the path to a program you can try?  Anyway, on a different tack, try diffing 'shopt -p' from the interactive and script cases.  Also see http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071106192548833 Also diff 'enable -pa'

Comment: `which echo` outputs `/bin/echo/` (already played with it...no new results). Interestingly, that link you provided had me retest `#!/bin/bash`, which I thought was in my script already, but it was still `#!/bin/sh`. Re-running with `/bin/bash` fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @user46874 You're running your echos and scripts from a shell which appends its own prompt to the output. Is there something you're editing out which may be significant - that prompt string does not match what is posted in your question. Now when I try to reproduce this my shell prompt is obscuring things such that I can't really reproduce it as cited.  OTOH it may have something to do with the terminal settings and your term it is set up to handle the control chars.

Comment: @JohnMee, That is indeed my `$PS1`. I stripped my actual prompt from the question as I didn't think it was significant.

Comment: @JohnMee, This setting might be important: **Terminal > Preferences > Advanced > Emulation > Declare terminal as > xterm-color**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had something to do with `#!/bin/sh` at the top of my script. After I changed it to `#!/bin/bash`, I saw the expected output.

Comment: That make sense.  `/bin/sh` is the POSIX compliant shell in OS X and will behave differently than `/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the same thing on my Mac, and got the same results.

I'm thinking two possibilities:

- One of your `set -o` or `shoot` settings might be doing this
- Your `.bashrc` (which would be called when you run a shell script) is doing something.

My results look like this:

```
$ echo -ne "hello\rbye"
bye$
$ test.sh   #Shell script with the one line in it
buy$ []
```

The `[]` represents the cursor. I have `$PS1="$ "`.

A suggesting, use `printf` if you want to do things like this.

```
$ printf "hello\rbye"
```

`printf` doesn't automatically add a CR line, and you don't have to give it any special options.

Comment: Your results are different in that yours replaces the whole line with "bye" (instead of overwriting the string already there). I switched my shell script to use `#!/bin/bash`, which seemed to work.